# curl CURLOPT_TIMEOUT doesnt works, script executes forever

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code

```
    function exit_ajax($ex_return_value,  $ex_ch=null, $ex_close_resource=false) {
    $output = array('return' => $ex_return_value);
    echo json_encode($output);
    if ($ex_close_resource)
        curl_close($ex_ch);
    exit();
}

#ini_set("display_errors",1);
#error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']))
    exit_ajax("server value unset");
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != 'XMLHttpRequest')
    exit_ajax("server value bad");
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$ch = curl_init();
if(!$ch)
    exit_ajax("CURL_INIT_NULL", $ch, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "t.co");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) exit_ajax("Errors: curl_getinfo: " . curl_getinfo($ch) . "; curl_error: " . curl_error($ch) . "; curl_errno: " . curl_errno($ch), $ch, true);

$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);  
curl_close($ch);    
exit_ajax("all fine");
```

It executes with ajax call from some page. If desired site is up, all works fine. If its down (502/504), that script is running forever. What do i change to make it return t/o error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the cURL problem.

While Website is UP - Request Status Gets 200(OK) and Script executes Fine

But

While Website is DOWN - The AJAX Request keeps sending/waiting for request until it gets 200(OK) Status.

Try Avoiding AJAX in this case and use PHP to send cURL Request.